# How to run a batch file when any folder is opened?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to know how to run a batch file when a folder is opened. I have create a batch file to install mysql server, now i want that installation to occur when folder containing that batch file is opened, here is my script.

```
@echo off
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...
msiexec /i "mysql-installer-community-5.6.14.0.msi" /qn
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. But you can tell your users to run the batch file instead.

Well, you could, but that would entail running a custom program on their computers and in *that* case you could simply do what the batch file does instead of waiting for a folder to be opened.